# date-fns how can I calculate the min age?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, date-fns

I use DateTimePicker and want to say the minimum age is 13. How can I say it ?

```
<DateTimePicker
...
minimumDate={new Date()}
/>
```

Comment: If you want to say the minimum age is 13, then you probably want to set the maximum date...

Comment: @Riwen yes you are right, but how can I calculate it ?

Answer (score 0):

I solvd it with:

```
<DateTimePicker
  maximumDate={subYears(new Date(), 13)}
/>
```